# Does equals apply on itself when looking an element in a list?

Tags: java, list, object, equals

I have an object list with a position value (x, y). When I ask if an object of this list is equals to the current object, does the function return true when comparate to itself in this list?

Basically:

```
foreach(MyObject o : list){
    foreach(MyObject o2 : list){
        if(o.equals(o2))
            doSomething();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(obj instanceof MyObject) 
    {
        MyObject tmp = (MyObject)obj;
        return this.getPosition().equals(tmp.getPosition());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes it would depending upon the implementation of equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish your loop to avoid returning a false positive when comparing an element to itself, you can add to your condition:

```
for (MyObject o : list){
    for (MyObject o2 : list){
        if (o != o2 && o.equals(o2))
            doSomething();
    }
}
```

This will ensure that only two distinct instances (which means `o` and `o2` don't refer to the same object) which are equal to each other will trigger `doSomething()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eran ;-)